# How do I open two Excel files (2010) on two separate screens?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would to have my current working file on main screen, and the file used to import data from on my side screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can open Excel form the start menu - this opens new instances, then open each file normally.

Or, the registry hack for this to become the normal behaviour

> Click on the Start button   Type `regedit` and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
>
> Next you need to navigate to the following registry entry
>
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOTExcel.Sheet.8shellOpencommand
>
> The (default) value will be something like this: `"C:Program Files
>   (x86)Microsoft OfficeOffice12EXCEL.EXE" /e`
>
> And you'll want to append a "%1" to the end of that, making it:
>
> "C:Program Files (x86)Microsoft OfficeOffice12EXCEL.EXE" /e "%1"
>
> Next you'll want to rename the command key, which is right below the
>   (Default) key, to command2 or something else.
>
> Next you'll need to rename the ddeexec key here to ddeexec2 or
>   something else:
>
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOTExcel.Sheet.8shellOpenddeexec
>
> This will make the change for the Excel 97-2003 filetype.
>
> If you want to do the same thing for Excel 2007 files, you'll need to
>   make the changes to the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOTExcel.Sheet.12 key.

[Source](http://blog.whitesites.com/Force-Windows-7-to-open-excel-documents-in-separate-windows__634014706378053750_blog.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows 7/8, open one instance of Excel, then hit your middle mouse button on  the application icon in your taskbar. This opens a new instance.